# created a website site1.com on local IIS. Now how to access it in browser

Tags: iis-7.5

I am following this video about IIS on [this](http://I%20am%20following%20this%20video%20about%20IIS%20on%20channel%209.%20If%20you%20just%20go%20on%20time%201:10%20in%20video,%20Steve%20creates%20a%20website%20site1.com%20and%20then%20access%20it%20on) link at channel9. If you just go on time 1:10 in video, Steve creates a website site1.com and then access it on 
browser via site1.com. When I do the same, i just get google search results back that site1.com not found. I am just not sure if you can access any website on your local machine  without having something like http://localhost/site1.com. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the domain to your HOSTS file.

```
127.0.0.1    site1.com www.site1.com
```

Comment: so it will be just for site1.com or should it be www.site1.com?

Comment: You can add another domain on the line. I'll update my answer to show you how.